# How to add letter to the beginning of each string element of the array?

Tags: scala

I have array with string elements.

```
val phoneNumbers = "7774589658,7056589658"
val arr = phoneNumbers.split(",")
```

My question is how to add letter to the beginning of each element of the array. For example:

```
[ "A7774589658", "A7056589658"]
```

I tried such code but it add letter to the end of each element of the array.

```
val result = arr.indices.foreach(arr(_) += "A")
```

Comment: `phoneNumbers.split(",").map("A" + _)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `map`

```
val result = arr.map("A"+_)
```